# Heroku: encapsulate data access in an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, api, heroku

I have a Heroku app with a PostgreSQL DB. Now I want to have a seperate process, possibly on a different machine, to access the DB. The suggestion on the Herkou site is actually what I wanted to do myself:

```
No, connecting to your database from machines outside of Heroku is not supported.
We recommend that you encapsulate data access in an API to manipulate it.
```

But I'm not sure how that's done best. I'd like to be able to send some JSON to the API and get back JSON as a result of that request. Like *"give me all posts that are expired for a bunch of given userIds"* or *"update all users to be suspended if their posts contain any of the given words"* in an example micropost app.

What's the best way to achieve that? Can I write an extra ruby program that is accessible via TCP and accepts JSON input? Is that even possible with Heroku? Or do I have to integrate the API into my rails app somehow? How?

Thankful for any ideas,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to integrate the API to your rails app, there are many solutions for this, one of them is using a tool specialized for API building like [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) and mount it with your Rails app. This way you could have your Rails app running and also the API, both sharing the same codebase.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll check that out. I would have preferred a stand-alone API, but I guess that's not possible with Heroku?

Comment: What do you mean by stand-alone API? A grape app would be mounted in a separate path of your rails app, they don't conflict with each other and you even get to share your models.

Comment: I'd want it to be as lean as possible without all that rails overhead. Like plain TCP calls to a ruby app that has access to the Heroku DB but only gives limited options to the caller. I wouldn't need to share models. The idea is to return plain data, like a list of integer values. The client is a node app that doesn't know sophisticated models but can only do fast calculation and distribution of the results. I'd be interested in a benchmark...